# Open file with "=" in its file name

Tags: c#, winforms, path, filenames

How do I manage to open a file with "=" in its path? I'm trying to do this, but it does not work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"/select, " + @"C:\te=st.srt");
```

Maybe the "=" can be replaced with something else in my code maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the filename on the command line in quotes:

```
@"/select, ""C:\te=st.srt"""
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution.